# an adverb or an object

Tags: grammar

e.g I went to the cinema last night

The word " the cinema " here is an object or an adverb ?

e.g We live in a house

The word " a house here is an object or an adverb ?

Comment: A noun cannot act as an adverb, but it can be the object of a preposition within [an adverbial phrase](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/adverbial_phrases.htm)

Comment: @CanadianYankee "I arrived [Monday](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Monday)." <-- A noun acts as an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *I went to the cinema last night.*
>
> [2] *We live in a house.*

In [1] "the cinema" is a noun phrase functioning as object complement of the preposition "to". Note that "to the cinema" is a preposition phrase functioning as complement of the verb "went".

In [2] "a house" is a noun phrase functioning as object complement of the preposition "in". Note that "in a house" is a preposition phrase functioning as complement of the verb "live".

Answer (score 0):

"the cinema" is two words!

The first word is a determiner.  The second word is a noun. There are no adverbs in these sentences. Together "the cinema" is a "noun phrase".

The phrase "the cinema" is the object *of the preposition "to"*.  The verb "go" doesn't have an object in this sentence, as it is an intransitive verb.

Comment: So I have a question, why these sentences have objects but the words live and go(went) are still instransitve verbs ?

Comment: @englishlearner No object in the sentences...